# Field of fractions of an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $A$ be an integral domain.
I want to prove that the field of fractions $ Q(A) := (A \setminus \{0\} \times A )/ \sim$ , with $ (a,b) \sim (c,d) \Leftrightarrow ad - cb = 0 $ , is actually a field.

We name the elements in $ Q(A) $, $\frac {a}{b} $ , meaning the equivalence class of $(a,b)$.

I know that $ Q(A) $ is a ring with the sum $ \frac {a}{b} + \frac {c}{d} = \frac {ad+cb}{bd}  $, and the product $ \frac {a}{b} \cdot \frac {c}{d}  = \frac {ac}{bd} $.

I have tried seeing if every element $ \frac {a}{b} \in Q(A) $ has an inverse , by doing this :

$ \frac {a}{b} \cdot \frac {x}{y} = \frac {1}{1}$ , then $\frac {ax}{by} = \frac {1}{1} $ , so I have $ (ax, by ) \sim (1,1) $ , but I do not know what to do next.

Comment: If $\frac{a}{b}\ne 0$, can you simply write down what its inverse must be, then prove it?

Comment: Why do you denote the field of fractions with a lowercase $a$?

Comment: For rationals $\,(a/b)^{-1} = b/a,\,$ by $(a.b)(b/a) = ab/(ab) = 1.\,$ Same here  $\ (a,b)(b,a) = (ab,ab) \sim (1,1)\ $  where $\,a,b\neq 0.\  $ For intuition, it helps to keep in mind the special case of rationals (and other concrete fraction fields you may already know). Generally whenever you meet an abstraction you should go back-and-forth between the abstract generalization and concrete examples in order to aid grasping the generalization.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$ (ax,by)\sim(1,1)\iff ax=by. $$
There is an obvious solution .